# Replacing a variable in an integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm translating my analytical solution into Wolfram Mathematica code. I came across a problem like replacing a variable in an integral. Please advise how best to implement it in WM. What comes to my mind is replacing one expression with another by using the "/." operator.

```
eq1 = SigmaPhi == 
  SigmaPhiBegin + 
   Integrate[
    SigmaPhiBegin [s] (s (a^2 - Kappa rho^2))/(
     rho^2 (a^2 - Kappa s^2)), {s, rho, BEnd}]

eq2 = eq1 /. rho^2 -> (a^2 (E^Eta - 1))/Kappa

eq3 = Assuming[{(a^2 (E^Eta - 1))/Kappa > 0}, 
  eq2 /. s -> Sqrt[(a^2 (E^EtaS - 1))/Kappa] /. rho -> Eta /. 
   BEnd -> BEndS]
```

Then I get a bunch of errors that I don’t know what to do with.

Since one of the limits of the integral is variable and is an out-of-integral term containing the desired function, we obtain an inhomogeneous Volterra equation of the 2nd kind.

$\sigma_{\phi_{end}}(\rho)=\sigma_{\phi_{begin}}(\rho)+\int_{\rho}^{b_{end}}\sigma_{\phi_{begin}}(s)\cdot\dfrac{s\cdot(a^2-\kappa\cdot\rho^2)}{\rho^2\cdot(a^2+\kappa\cdot s^2)}\,ds;$

For ease of integration, we introduce a new variable:

$\eta=\ln(1+\kappa\cdot(\dfrac{\rho}{a})^2);$

$e^{\eta}=(1+\kappa\cdot(\dfrac{\rho}{a})^2);$

$\rho^2=\dfrac{a^2\cdot(e^\eta-1)}{\kappa};$

We substitute it into our equation and reduce similar terms and factors:

$\sigma_{\phi_{end}}(\rho(\eta))=\sigma_{\phi_{begin}}(\rho(\eta))+\int_{\rho(\eta)}^{b_{end}}\sigma_{\phi_{begin}}(s)\cdot\dfrac{s\cdot(a^2-\kappa\cdot\dfrac{a^2\cdot(e^\eta-1)}{\kappa})}{\dfrac{a^2\cdot(e^\eta-1)}{\kappa}\cdot(a^2+\kappa\cdot s^2)}\,ds;$

$\sigma_{\phi_{end}}(\rho(\eta))=\sigma_{\phi_{begin}}(\rho(\eta))+\int_{\rho(\eta)}^{b_{end}}\sigma_{\phi_{begin}}(s)\cdot\dfrac{(2-e^{\eta})\cdot\kappa\cdot s}{(e^{\eta}-1)\cdot(a^2+\kappa\cdot s^2)}\,ds;$

$\sigma_{\phi_{end}}(\rho(\eta))=\sigma_{\phi_{begin}}(\rho(\eta))+\dfrac{(2-e^{\eta})\cdot\kappa}{e^{\eta}-1}\cdot\int_{\rho(\eta)}^{b_{end}}\sigma_{\phi_{begin}}(s)\cdot\dfrac{s}{a^2+\kappa\cdot s^2}\,ds;$

We change the integration variable and reduce similar terms and factors:

$s^2=\dfrac{a^2\cdot(e^{\eta_{s}}-1)}{\kappa};$

$\eta_{s}=\ln(1+\kappa\cdot(\frac{s}{a})^2);$

$d\eta_{s}=\dfrac{2\cdot\kappa\cdot s}{a^2\cdot(1+\kappa\cdot(\frac{s}{a})^2)}\,ds;$

$ds=\dfrac{a^2+\kappa\cdot s^2}{2\cdot\kappa\cdot s}\,d\eta;$

$\sigma_{\phi_{end}}(\eta)=\sigma_{\phi_{begin}}(\eta)+\dfrac{(2-e^{\eta})\cdot\kappa}{e^{\eta}-1}\cdot\int_{\eta(\rho(\eta))}^{\eta(b_{end})}\sigma_{\phi_{begin}}(\eta_{s})\cdot\dfrac{s}{a^2+\kappa s^2}\cdot\dfrac{a^2+\kappa\cdot s^2}{2\cdot\kappa\cdot s}\,ds;$

$\sigma_{\phi_{end}}(\eta)=\sigma_{\phi_{begin}}(\eta)+\dfrac{2-e^{\eta}}{2\cdot(e^{\eta}-1)}\cdot\int_{\eta}^{\eta(b_{end})}\sigma_{\phi_{begin}}(\eta_{s})\,d\eta_{s};$

We replace the integral with a function and substitute it into the previous equation:

$f(\eta)=\int_{\eta}^{\eta(b_{end})}\sigma_{\phi_{begin}}(\eta_{s})\,d\eta_{s};$

$\sigma_{\phi_{end}}(\eta)=\sigma_{\phi_{begin}}(\eta)+\dfrac{2-e^{\eta}}{2\cdot(e^{\eta}-1)}\cdot f(\eta);$

We take the derivative with respect to the lower limit of the integral:

$f(\eta)^{'}_{\eta}=-\sigma_{\phi_{begin}}(\eta);$

We reduce the integral equation to a first-order inhomogeneous differential equation:

$f(\eta)^{'}_{\eta}=-(\sigma_{\phi_{end}}(\eta)+\dfrac{e^{\eta}-2}{2\cdot(e^{\eta}-1)}\cdot f(\eta));$

We solve the corresponding homogeneous equation and reduce it to the form with separated variables:

$\dfrac{df(\eta)}{f(\eta)}=-\dfrac{e^{\eta}-2}{2\cdot(e^{\eta}-1)}\,d\eta;$

Auxiliary calculations of the right-hand side integral:

$\int\dfrac{e^{\eta}-2}{e^{\eta}-1}\,d\eta=\int(1-\dfrac{1}{e^\eta-1})\,d\eta=\eta-\int\dfrac{e^\eta d\eta}{e^\eta\cdot(e^\eta-1)}=\eta-\int\dfrac{de^\eta}{e^{2\cdot\eta}-e^\eta}=$

$=\eta-\int\dfrac{de^\eta}{e^{2\cdot\eta}-2\cdot e^\eta\cdot\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{4}}=\eta-\int\dfrac{de^\eta}{(e^{\eta}-\frac{1}{2})^2-\frac{1}{4}}=\eta-\frac{1}{2\cdot\frac{1}{2}}\cdot\ln|\dfrac{e^\eta-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}}{e^\eta-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}}|=$

$=\eta+\ln|\dfrac{e^\eta}{e^\eta-1}|+A;$

$\ln|f(\eta)|=-\frac{1}{2}\cdot(\eta+\ln|\dfrac{e^\eta}{e^\eta-1}|)+B;$

We obtain a solution for the homogeneous equation:

$f(\eta)=(\dfrac{e^{2\cdot\eta}}{e^\eta-1})^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot C1;$

Now we find a solution to the inhomogeneous differential equation and represent $C1$ as a function of $\eta:$

$f(\eta)=(\dfrac{e^{2\cdot\eta}}{e^\eta-1})^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot C1(\eta);$

We take the derivative of the function with respect to $\eta:$

$f(\eta)^{'}_{\eta}=-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\dfrac{2\cdot e^{2\cdot\eta}\cdot(e^\eta-1)-e^{\eta}\cdot e^{2\cdot\eta}}{(e^\eta-1)^2}\cdot(\dfrac{e^{2\cdot\eta}}{e^\eta-1})^{-\frac{3}{2}}\cdot C1(\eta)+(\dfrac{e^{2\cdot\eta}}{e^\eta-1})^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot C1(\eta)^{'}_{\eta}=$

$=(\dfrac{e^{2\cdot\eta}}{e^\eta-1})^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot C1(\eta)^{'}_{\eta}-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\dfrac{(e^{3\cdot\eta}-2\cdot e^{2\cdot\eta})\cdot e^{-3\cdot\eta}}{(e^\eta-1)^2\cdot(e^\eta-1)^{-\frac{3}{2}}}\cdot C1(\eta)=$

$=(\dfrac{e^{2\cdot\eta}}{e^\eta-1})^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot C1(\eta)^{'}_{\eta}-\dfrac{e^{-\eta}\cdot(e^\eta-2)}{2\cdot(e^\eta-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}}\cdot C1(\eta);$

We substitute into the original remote control, reduce similar factors and terms:

$(\dfrac{e^{2\cdot\eta}}{e^\eta-1})^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot C1(\eta)^{'}_{\eta}-\dfrac{e^{-\eta}\cdot(e^\eta-2)}{2\cdot(e^\eta-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}}\cdot C1(\eta)=-\sigma_{\phi_{end}}(\eta)-\dfrac{e^{\eta}-2}{2\cdot(e^{\eta}-1)}\cdot(\dfrac{e^{2\cdot\eta}}{e^\eta-1})^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot C1(\eta);$

We reduce the DE to the form with separated variables and solve it:

$\dfrac{\sqrt{e^\eta-1}}{e^\eta}\cdot dC1(\eta)=-\sigma_{\phi_{end}}(\eta)\,d\eta;$

$dC1(\eta)=-\dfrac{e^\eta}{\sqrt{e^\eta-1}}\cdot\sigma_{\phi_{end}}(\eta)\,d\eta;$

$C1(\eta)=-\int^{\eta}_{\eta(b_{end})}\dfrac{e^{\eta_s}}{\sqrt{e^{\eta_s}-1}}\cdot\sigma_{\phi_{end}}({\eta_s})\,d{\eta_s}+D;$

We substitute $C1(\eta)$ into the required function:

$f(\eta)=(\dfrac{e^{2\cdot\eta}}{e^\eta-1})^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot(-\int^{\eta}_{\eta(b_{end})}\dfrac{e^{\eta_s}}{\sqrt{e^{\eta_s}-1}}\cdot\sigma_{\phi_{end}}({\eta_s})\,d{\eta_s}+D);$

We solve the Cauchy problem: the limits of the integral coincide at $\eta=\eta(b_{end})$ - the function we introduced becomes equal to 0:

$0=(\dfrac{e^{2\cdot\eta(b_{end})}}{e^{\eta(b_{end})}-1})^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot(-\int^{\eta(b_{end})}_{\eta(b_{end})}\dfrac{e^{\eta_s}}{\sqrt{e^{\eta_s}-1}}\cdot\sigma_{\phi_{end}}({\eta_s})\,d{\eta_s}+D);$

$f(\eta)=\dfrac{\sqrt{e^{\eta}-1}}{e^{\eta}}\cdot(-\int^{\eta}_{\eta(b_{end})}\dfrac{e^{\eta_s}}{\sqrt{e^{\eta_s}-1}}\cdot\sigma_{\phi_{end}}({\eta_s})\,d{\eta_s});$

$\sigma_{\phi_{begin}}(\eta)=\sigma_{\phi_{end}}(\eta)+\dfrac{e^{\eta}-2}{2\cdot(e^{\eta}-1)}\cdot f(\eta);$

$\sigma_{\phi_{begin}}(\eta)=\sigma_{\phi_{end}}(\eta)+\dfrac{e^{\eta}-2}{2\cdot e^{\eta}\cdot\sqrt{e^{\eta}-1}}\cdot\int_{\eta}^{\eta(b_{end})}\dfrac{e^{\eta_s}}{\sqrt{e^{\eta_s}-1}}\cdot\sigma_{\phi_{end}}({\eta_s})\,d{\eta_s};$

We reversely replace the variable $\eta$ with $\rho$:

$e^{\eta}=(1+\kappa\cdot(\dfrac{\rho}{a})^2);$

$\eta=\ln(1+\kappa\cdot(\dfrac{s}{a})^2);$

$d\eta=\dfrac{2\cdot\kappa\cdot\frac{s}{a^2}}{1+\kappa\cdot(\frac{s}{a})^2}\,ds=\dfrac{2\cdot\kappa\cdot s}{a^2+\kappa\cdot s^2}\,ds;$

$\sigma_{\phi_{begin}}(\rho)=\sigma_{\phi_{end}}(\rho)+\dfrac{(1+\kappa\cdot(\dfrac{\rho}{a})^2)-2}{2\cdot (1+\kappa\cdot(\dfrac{\rho}{a})^2)\cdot\sqrt{(1+\kappa\cdot(\dfrac{\rho}{a})^2)-1}}\cdot\int_{\rho}^{b_{end}}\dfrac{(1+\kappa\cdot(\dfrac{s}{a})^2)}{\sqrt{(1+\kappa\cdot(\dfrac{s}{a})^2)-1}}\cdot$

$\cdot\sigma_{\phi_{end}}({s})\cdot\dfrac{2\cdot\kappa\cdot s}{a^2+\kappa\cdot s^2}\,ds;$

We reduce similar factors and terms:

$\sigma_{\phi_{begin}}(\rho)=\sigma_{\phi_{end}}(\rho)+\dfrac{(\kappa\cdot\rho^2-a^2)\cdot a}{2\cdot\sqrt{\kappa}\cdot(\kappa\cdot\rho^2+a^2)\cdot\rho}\cdot\int_{\rho}^{b_{end}}\dfrac{a^2+\kappa\cdot s^2}{a\cdot\sqrt{\kappa}\cdot s}\cdot\sigma_{\phi_{end}}({s})\cdot\dfrac{2\cdot\kappa\cdot s}{a^2+\kappa\cdot s^2}\,ds;$

We get the answer:

$\sigma_{\phi_{begin}}(\rho)=\sigma_{\phi_{end}}(\rho)+\dfrac{\kappa\cdot\rho^2-a^2}{(\kappa\cdot\rho^2+a^2)\cdot\rho}\cdot\int_{\rho}^{b_{end}}\sigma_{\phi_{end}}({s})\,ds.$

Comment: Please show us your Mathematica code that you have tried so far. You certainly do not expect this community to retype all of this in Mathematica, right? :)

Comment: **I came across a problem like replacing a variable in an integral.** why not make a small minimal example just for this? if you make MWE specific to the issue, you will get better help.

Comment: @Nasser, I added the beginning of the code where the first problems appeared.

Comment: You seem to be trying to change the integration variable itself to a compound expression. This is not correct. ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJupa.png)  you will get an error **Invalid integration variable** . The integration variable has to be a single symbol. May be you want to look at **IntegrateChangeVariables** ? see help for examples.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you want to change the integration variable from `s` to `EtaS` (shouldn't start user-defined symbol names with capitals, though).  I'll take the integral out and work on that. `IntegrateChangeVariables` didn't work for me, so I'll do it step by step. `Dt[var]` is good for doing the u-sub thing with the derivative where $dx$ becomes ${dx \over du} du$.  First we break down $\int_a^b f\; dx$ into parts `{f Dt[x], x == a, x == b}`; then sub, and solve/simplify each part.

```
myInt = First@Cases[eq2, _Integrate, Infinity];
myIntParts = 
  Replace[myInt, 
   Verbatim[Integrate][f_, {x_, a_, b_}] :> {f  Dt[x], x == a, x == b}];
firstSub = myIntParts /. s -> Sqrt[(a^2  (E^EtaS - 1))/Kappa]; (* u-sub *)
secondSub = firstSub /. {Dt[EtaS] -> Dt[EtaS], _Dt -> 0}; (* non-EtaS is const *)
thirdSub = Replace[secondSub, {eq_Equal :> Solve[eq, EtaS]}, 1] // Simplify; (* solve end points *)
Replace[thirdSub, {f_  HoldPattern[Dt[x_]], {{a_Rule}}, {{b_Rule}}} :>
   Integrate[f, {x, x /. a, x /. b}]] (* reassemble integral *)
```

$$\int_{\log \left(\frac{\text{Kappa} \rho
   ^2}{a^2}+1\right)}^{\log \left(\frac{\text{BEnd}^2
   \text{Kappa}}{a^2}+1\right)} \frac{a^2
   \left(e^{\text{Eta}}-2\right) e^{\text{EtaS}}
   \text{SigmaPhiBegin}\left(\sqrt{\frac{a^2
   \left(e^{\text{EtaS}}-1\right)}{\text{Kappa}}}\right)}
   {2 \left(e^{\text{EtaS}}-2\right) \text{Kappa} \rho
   ^2} \, d\text{EtaS}$$

Comment: thanks for the answer. Please tell me what needs to be changed so that the lower limit rho is changed to Eta (is an inverse function of rho, which means Eta(rho(Eta)) = Eta), and the upper limit BEnd is changed to BEndS. And change SigmaPhiBegin[s] to depend on the EtaS variable - SigmaPhiBegin[EtaS].